# How to troubleshoot crashes detected by Google Play Store for Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have a flutter app I am trying to publish to Google Play store.

Play store is saying the app is crashing on Pixel 2 (api 28) with below error. Other devices they use for testing don't get this error.

Could not find anything on this error. When I test on Pixel 2 (api 28) emulator on my PC the app does not crash.

How can I troubleshoot this?

```
Abort message: 'vendor/unbundled_google/libs/ndk_translation/ndk_translation/ir/include/ndk_translation/ir/ir.h:685: 
CHECK failed: IsAligned(offset, GetFormatSize(format))'
```

Comment: Same exact problem here. Play Store rejects with same error on Pixel 2 (api 28) but runs fine on my dev machine with the Pixel 2 emulator. Help!!

Comment: I ended up changing minimum API to 29, that fixed it...

Comment: I see, thanks, I'm trying it now. I'm guessing that doesn't really "fix" the problem, it just means that Google won't test against the Pixel 2 or any other version less than API 29 (Android 10). So does that mean all those tens of millions of Android 9, 8, 7 users and less won't be able to access it from Play Store?

Comment: I think there's a problem with Google's emulator...

Comment: This is the relevant issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the current release of Flutter. The problem goes away if you use the current beta 3.1.0-9.0.pre as follows:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade 3.1.0
flutter clean
flutter build appbundle --release
```

This allowed me to use minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 31 and still pass the Play Store review.

Comment: This is the relevant issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105903